# How can i get animation when click a button that in List?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-animation, swiftui-button

My code is like this:

```
       List {
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Text("Button")
            })
        }
```

when click button, it has none animation, it's not change the opacity, this not change backgroud color. But when press button, the backgroud color is changed.
this result is:
[image]

The effect I except is click button and backgroud color changed immediately, like this:
[image]

I try to set buttonStyle by using code

```
struct clickButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .background(configuration.isPressed ? Color.gray : Color.white)
    }
}
```

but the result is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second image you provided is the default behavior of the `NavigationLink`:

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            NavigationLink("Button") {
                Text("Next")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the issue you reported is because the `buttonStyle` is `automatic` when you use it in a `list`. You can change it to anything but the `automatic`. like:

```
List {
    Button(action: {}, label: {
        Text("Button")
    })
}
.buttonStyle(.borderless) //  Here
```